# matplotlib: what's the difference with set_major_formatter() and fmt_xdata?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib. And I copied code for simple pyqt-matplotlib example from [here](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-matplotlib/), and changed `plot()` of `class PlotCanvas` to make a Value-Time chart.

```
  def plot(self):
    dates = mdates.drange(dt.datetime(2010, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2010,1,2),
                  dt.timedelta(minutes=10))
    y_val = [random.random() for i in range(len(dates))]

    ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(dates, y_val)

    use_major_formatter = True
    if use_major_formatter:
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d %H:%M'))
    else:
        ax.fmt_xdata = DateFormatter('%%m-%d %H:%M')
    self.figure.autofmt_xdate()

    ax.set_title('PyQt Matplotlib Example')
    self.draw()
```

Above code requires theseimports:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
```

I tried `set_major_formatter()` and `fmt_xdata`. And I've found `fmt_xdata` doesn't work.

But why?
What's the difference with set_major_formatter() and fmt_xdata?

Notice: In the above code, I added `if` statement to test two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter()` and `ax.fmt_xdata` are entirely different things.

The first, `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter()`, sets the formatter for the x axis in your plot. This is useful for showing the ticklabels in a required format.

The second, `ax.fmt_xdata` is a function that takes in a data coordinate and formats it. It will by default just return the same as the major formatter. It is used internally to format the numbers in the GUI that are shown when moving the mouse around.

[image]

You can replace the `ax.fmt_xdata` method by your own custom callable in case you want the GUI to show different numbers/strings than your axis.